# VSIX CS0426 The type name Views does not exist in the type 'ABC'

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, vsix

I'm creating a VSIX plug-in and just added a WPF control like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ABC.Views.Configuration.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ABC.Views.Configuration"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I compile the project I am getting the error:
CS0426  The type name Views does not exist in the type 'ABC'

I've checked the projects' default namespace and other relevant configurations and everything looks good.  In fact, I have other User Controls in the same directory that are compiling just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this problem was this line in XAML above:

```
Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
```

For some reason VSIX doesn't like wiring events in XAML.  I simply removed this and wired it up in Code-behind